# Horizontal scroll bar is not visible for some devices

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, scrollbar, horizontalscrollview

In android I implimented horizontal scroll view n set the scroll bars true for that,

But in some device's it's visible but other it's not where I'm going wrong can you suggest

Also both devices are in android 10 only

Also I have set fade as false

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add these two lines in your recyclerView xml

```
android:scrollbarFadeDuration="0"
android:scrollbarDefaultDelayBeforeFade="0"
```

Comment: But I have set fade as false alredy
My it's visible in my phone but not in my friends phone

Comment: remove that and put the above lines.

Comment: tried but problem continues on realme 3pro device only, on other devices it works fine